# How can I make Nuget Gallery support mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, nugetgallery

I git clone the [Nuget Gallery](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery), and it's based on the sql server.

As the NuGet gallery use the entityframework 6, I was trying to migrate to the mysql following the below steps:

**1.Replace the connectionStrings of web.config with below**

```
<add name="Gallery.SqlServer" connectionString="server=localhost;uid=root;password=123456;database=NuGetGallery" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
<add name="Gallery.SupportRequestSqlServer" connectionString="server=localhost;userid=root;password=123456;database=SupportRequest" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

**2.Replace the entityframework section with below:**

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="NuGetGallery.EntitiesConfiguration, NuGetGallery.Core">
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
</providers>
```

**3.Replace `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(EntitiesConfiguration))]` with `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]`
 for *EntitiesContext* and *SupportRequestDbContext***

**4.Replace the EntitiesConfiguration() constrcutor with**

```
    public EntitiesConfiguration()
    {
        // Configure Connection Resiliency / Retry Logic
        // See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.aspx and msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn307226
        SetExecutionStrategy(MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, () => new MySqlExecutionStrategy());
    }
```

But, get no luck!

When I execute `Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName MigrationsConfiguration -Verbose`, it raised an exception as below:

> Using StartUp project 'NuGetGallery'.
>      Using NuGet project 'NuGetGallery'.
>      Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
>      System.NullReferenceException: 未将对象引用设置到对象的实例。
>         在 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
>         在 System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
>         在 System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
>         在 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`3 k)
>         在 System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>         在 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
>         在 System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
>         在 System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
>         在 System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
>         在 System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
>         在 System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>         在 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes()
>         在 System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
>         在 NuGetGallery.ObjectMaterializedInterceptingDbContext.get_ObjectContext() 位置 E:\git\HSY.NugetGallery\src\NuGetGallery.Core\Entities\Interception\ObjectMaterializedInterceptingDbContext.cs:行号 35
>         在 NuGetGallery.ObjectMaterializedInterceptingDbContext..ctor(String connectionString) 位置 E:\git\HSY.NugetGallery\src\NuGetGallery.Core\Entities\Interception\ObjectMaterializedInterceptingDbContext.cs:行号 19
>         在 NuGetGallery.EntitiesContext..ctor(String connectionString, Boolean readOnly) 位置 E:\git\HSY.NugetGallery\src\NuGetGallery.Core\Entities\EntitiesContext.cs:行号 42
>         在 NuGetGallery.EntitiesContext..ctor() 位置 E:\git\HSY.NugetGallery\src\NuGetGallery.Core\Entities\EntitiesContext.cs:行号 34

Comment: did you try: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/2923

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the same issue. And as you can see, I already used "ConfigurationTypeName" to specify the configuration

Comment: You did not specify the project though `-StartUpProjectName NuGetGallery`

Comment: If you're open to considering other solutions, BaGet is a lightweight NuGet package manager that supports MySQL and various cloud-based or local deployment options: https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet